# TypeSafe Activator keeps giving me Errors when trying to start it up

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I'm trying to work on a project with Typesafe Activator. Everytime I've tried running Activator it says it does not find Activator in the project.

The errors I'm getting:

> C:\GETTINREAL\bin>activator ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\GETTINREAL
>
> The system cannot find the file BIN_DIRECTORY..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.
>
> The system cannot find the file C:\Documents and
>   Settings\James.activator\1.3.1 0\activatorconfig.txt.
>
> The system cannot find the file C:\Documents and
>   Settings\James.activator\activ atorconfig.txt.   Did not detect an
>   activator project in this directory.

The project is in Play 2.5 and I'm on windows XP. I've tried setting the environmental variable ACTIVATOR_HOME to the root activator folder and still no luck. The project I'm trying to run works fine on my other (win8) computer, I've pulled the code off github and am trying to run it with the above errors.

Comment: Your code on github should contain just the application code, but not the activator itself.Is activator installed on your XP?

Comment: Hey, sorry just now saw this. Yea activator was installed but it would keep looking in the wrong directory. I eventually got it working by just putting the libexec folder to the directory it kept looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your fist experience with Play, this [link](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/play-framework-getting-started.html) may be helpful.